# PostgreSQL ERROR: must be owner of schema public

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am new to Postgres and am having an issue dropping all tables in a database. I have a database named "mvp" and the owner is set as "postgres." I did the following in my terminal:

```
psql -d mvp postgres -W
postgres=> \l
                            List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |  Access privileges  
-----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+---------------------
 mvp       | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
postgres=> \c mvp
You are now connected to database "mvp" as user "postgres".
mvp=> DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;
ERROR:  must be owner of schema public
```

It is showing that I am logged in as the user "postgres" which happens to be the owner of the "mvp" database. However, I am receiving an error message saying I am not the owner.

Comment: To your question add the answers to the following commands run in `psql` 1) select version();  2) `\du postgres` 3) `\dn public`

Comment: The `\l` does confirm that postgres is the owner of the database. However, the error messages says that postgres is not the owner of the **schema**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have changed the ownership of schema `public` before, `postgres` (the owner of the database) would be the owner of that schema. So you'd have to connect as user `postgres` or a superuser to drop the schema.

To approach that methodically:

- find out who owns schema `public`

  ```
  \dn public
  ```
- become that user

  ```
  \c - username
  ```
- drop the schema

  ```
  DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;
  ```